# Can't add new row to DataGrid, while it has combobox that bind ItemsSource to same object as DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

the concept is,I want a field in record link to other record primarykey
so I have ComboBox in "DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate"
and bound that ComboBox.ItemsSource to same as DataGrid.ItemsSource
my source code are this

```
<DataGrid Name="CollectionGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Gray" CornerRadius="10">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CollectionGrid, Path=ItemsSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Ref, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

and the code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public ObservableCollection<PACKET> DB { set; get; }
    public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        DB = new ObservableCollection<PACKET>();
        DB.Add(new PACKET { ID = 1, Name = "TEST1", Ref = 1});
        DB.Add(new PACKET { ID = 2, Name = "TEST2", Ref = 1 });
        DB.Add(new PACKET { ID = 3, Name = "TEST3", Ref = 1 });

        CollectionGrid.ItemsSource = DB;
        }
    }

public class PACKET
    {
    public Int64 ID  { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public Int64 Ref { set; get; }
    }
```

the program can showup ComboBox items properly,
I can change selected item
the problem is when I try to add new row to DataGrid
it said

[image]

any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to the ComboBox. You can't insert a new row into the table if doing so creates a null PK. Make it an identify column.

Comment: but if I remove ComboBox control, it can insert new row properly

Comment: Google "DeferRefresh is not allowed". It's related to control focus and seems to happen with several WPF controls. Mostly DataGrid and TabControl. I'd be willing to bet that when you click the combo box, the datagrid loses focus and creates the error.

Comment: no, it's not that event..
in above example, there's 3 records in collection..
after program running, it can poppulate combobox
and I can click / change selection of any combobox properly
the error occur when I double click on new row of DataGrid
and if I remove just the binding of ComboBox
it can work all properly but no item in combobox due to ItemsSource lack